# How to go to the first blank cell directly in a column of Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I use column A mainly. A1 is the name of data type, and A2, A3, A4, ... are data. When I open this file, It shows the screen containing the first cell, A1. If I fill data from A2 to A250, then I should scroll down to the cell A251 to fill the next data.

It takes some time, and I want to know the way (if exists) to go to the first blank cell of column A when I open this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you need onOpen script for your task like this:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var spreadsheet = e.source;
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  if (sheet.getMaxRows() == lastRow) {
    sheet.appendRow([""]);
  }
  lastRow = lastRow + 1;
  var range = sheet.getRange("A" + lastRow + ":A" + lastRow);
  sheet.setActiveRange(range);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow Down</kbd>).
It will take you directly to the cell before the first empty cell. if you are using MAC it would be <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow Down</kbd>

Comment: Oh yeah, please give me solutions that don't make me add more code into the world!