# Scroll to first blank cell Google Sheets on top

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am trying to create a, only on Open, function to go to the first blank cell of a specific sheets column in Google Sheets

**Update** I currently have a script that works - but it's quite slow onOpen. What are some possible ways to speed it up? The script:

```
function onOpen(e) {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
  spreadsheet.getRange('C1').activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).activate();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show one of the scripts that you tried and describe what you tried to do to solve the problem. Ref. [ask].

Comment: Hi Ruben. I'll try to follow how to ask best practices in the future, thanks for pointing that out. I attached a script from [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/130670/how-to-go-to-the-first-blank-cell-directly-in-a-column-of-google-sheets), changed columns, but with no luck.

Comment: Questions should be self-contained, to do that, add the script with the changes that you maid. If you got an error message also add it textually.

Comment: Hi Ruben. Through a macro, I was able to get something to work. However, it is quite slow at the moment, possibly due to the sheet having 70 columns and 700+ rows. Nonetheless, do you maybe have some suggestions to how I can improve the speed?

Comment: Hi Nuxurious. The spreadsheet size might be a factor but I think that other factor that has a bigger impact is the use of many `getCurrentCell()` and `.activate()` because they depend on the active user. Take a look to [Script to have Google Sheets jump to the next available row in column A automatically?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/101197/88163) for other options.